# A student guesses/knows/copies answer in exam, what is the probability that if answer is correct, he had guessed it

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**Question:**

In a multiple choice questions examination it is known that a student guesses or copies or knows an answer.  Probability that he guesses  is $1/3$, he copies is $1/6$. If the answer of student is correct, what is the probability that he guessed the answer?

---

**My attempt:**

First of all, I calculated the probability that he knows the answer which is equal to $1 -\frac13 - \frac16 = \frac12$.

Now, I  think I've to apply Baye's theorem here. But it seems like the information given in the question is not enough to solve the problem.

If I consider $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ be the events that he guesses the answer, copies the answer and knows the answer respectively and also let $A$ be the event that his answer is correct, then I've to calculate $P(E_1|A)$.

- $P(E_1) = \frac13$
- $P(E_2) = \frac16$
- $P(E_3) = \frac12$

On applying Baye's theorem, we have that:
$$P(E_1|A) = \frac{P(E_1) P(A|E_1)}{P(E_1) P(A|E_1) + P(E_3) P(A|E_3) + P(E_3) P(A|E_3)}.$$

Now I don't have the value of $P(A)$. How would I calculate that? Although $P(A|E_3)$ is $1$ which is easy to find.... if he knows the answer, then surely his answer would be correct but we just can't calculate $P(A|E_1), P(A|E_2) $ and $P(A|E_3)$ without knowing $P(A)$.

Isn't the data provided in the question incomplete?

Comment: You're correct -- you need to know the probability of a correct answer if the student guesses.

Comment: Well...it seems we need the probability that a guessed answer is correct, and the same for a copied answer.  I assume that, if the student knows the answer, it is correct.

Comment: @lulu I would even assume that a copied answer is always correct.

Comment: @RobertShore  Why?

Comment: @RobertShore That's not always true I think. What if he has copied from a student who had attempted it wrongly?

Comment: Were you told that there were $4$ choices?  That information doesn't appear in the post.  And, as you see from the comments, there is disagreement as to whether we are to assume that copied answers are correct.  I would say there's no reason to assume that...but in the absence of any other information, maybe we are to assume it?  Though, of course, in that case it's hard to see why that is introduced as a special category.

Comment: Regardless of those issues, we need those probabilities.  If the information is not provided, then assumptions have to be made.  Whatever assumptions you make, you should be sure to state clearly and explicitly.

Comment: I don't think we can assume that a copied answer is always correct.

Comment: @Utkarsh I agree. Copying something wrong does not make it right.

Comment: @Utkarsh I would agree in the real world, but in the context of this problem I think we have to assume that.